# Insert mode mapping in Vim

Tags: vim, keymapping

This may be trivial but I couldn't find a way to make this mapping work.

I have the following mapping in my `.vimrc` to compile a file using `clang` and run it afterwards:

```
map <F5> :wa \| !clang++ -g -std=c++11 % -o test && ./test : <CR>
```

I want to add the same mapping in insert mode but I doesn't seem to work. One of the many things I've tried (including wrapping the mapping in a separate function) was:

```
 imap <F5> <C-o> <F5>
```

How can I make this mapping work in insert mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the space after `<C-o>`. To get it work, I also needed to use `nnoremap` instead of `map`. So this should work:

```
nnoremap <F5> :wa \| !clang++ -g -std=c++11 % -o test && ./test : <CR>
imap <F5> <C-o><F5>
```